# Existence of infinitely many integers $n$ such that $2^n$ ends with $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Can anyone please help me on the following proof:

Prove that there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $2^n$ ends with $n$ in decimal notation, i.e. $2n = \ldots n$.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to show there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $2^n-n\equiv0\pmod{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor+1}}$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but isn't this more difficult to prove

Comment: Since it is only a mathematical statement of your problem, it don't see how it could be more difficult.

Comment: BTW, see http://oeis.org/A064541.

Comment: Why the edit?? It's now a totally different question!

Comment: I changed your question back to the question to which the answerers provided and directed their answers. If you want to ask a different question, I encourage you to ask a different question *but* in a different post.

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

$$2^{36} = \dots 36$$
$$2^{736} = \dots 736$$
$$2^{8736} = \dots 8736$$
$$2^{48736} = \dots 48736$$
$$\dots$$
$$2^{5075353432948736} = \dots 5075353432948736$$
(I would add more, but there is an important football match going on at the moment)

**Edit:**

(I am not sure if this is a homework question, or a contest question, so just another hint)

You might try to prove that $2^{10^m}\equiv 1 \pmod{5^m}$ for $m\geq2$ (by induction).

Comment: Actually, I needed to show $2^{10^m}\equiv1\pmod{5^{m+1}}$ for $m\ge2$. I used the [totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) rather than induction.

Comment: Yes, you are right about needing $5^{m+1}$. It didn't occur to me to use the totient function, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\phi(5^{n+1})=4\cdot5^n$, for $n\ge2.$
$$
2^{10^n}\equiv1\pmod{5^{n+1}}\tag{1}
$$
Suppose for some $n\ge2$,
$$
2^k\equiv k\pmod{10^n}\quad\text{and}\quad k\equiv0\pmod{2^n}\tag{2}
$$
then, for some $0\le a\lt5$, we have
$$
2^k\equiv a5^n+k\pmod{5^{n+1}}\tag{3}
$$
Multiplying $(3)$ by a power of $(1)$ yields
$$
2^{d10^n+k}\equiv a5^n+k\pmod{5^{n+1}}\tag{4}
$$
Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can find $0\le d\lt10$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
d&\equiv a3^n&\pmod{5}\tag{5}\\
d&\equiv k/2^n&\pmod{2}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
$(5)$ implies that $a\equiv d2^n\pmod{5}$ which in turn implies
$$
a5^n\equiv d10^n\pmod{5^{n+1}}\tag{7}
$$
$(4)$ and $(7)$ yield
$$
2^{d10^n+k}\equiv d10^n+k\pmod{5^{n+1}}\tag{8}
$$
$(6)$ implies that $d5^n+k/2^n\equiv0\pmod{2}$ which in turn implies
$$
d10^n+k\equiv0\pmod{2^{n+1}}\tag{9}
$$
$2^k\equiv k\pmod{10^n}\Rightarrow k\gt0$. Thus, $(9)$ implies $d10^n+k\ge2^{n+1}$ which implies 
$$
2^{d10^n+k}\equiv0\pmod{2^{n+1}}\tag{10}
$$
Therefore, $(9)$ and $(10)$ gives
$$
2^{d10^n+k}\equiv d10^n+k\pmod{2^{n+1}}\tag{11}
$$
Thus, $(8)$, $(9)$, and $(11)$ yield the $n+1$ equivalent of $(2)$:
$$
2^{d10^n+k}\equiv d10^n+k\pmod{10^{n+1}}\quad\text{and}\quad d10^n+k\equiv0\pmod{2^{n+1}}\tag{12}
$$
where $d$ is computed from $(3)$, $(5)$, and $(6)$.

Iterating $(3)$, $(5)$, $(6)$, and $(12)$, gives a sequence of $k$ that satisfy $(2)$.

---

**Example**

For $n=2$, only $k=36$ satisfies $(2)$.

$2^{36}\equiv3\cdot5^2+36\pmod{5^3}$, so $a=3$. Thus, we need to solve
$$
\begin{align}
d&\equiv 3\cdot3^2\equiv2&\pmod{5}\\
d&\equiv 36/2^2\equiv1&\pmod{2}
\end{align}
$$
so $d=7$, and the next term in the sequence is $k=736$ for $n=3$.

$2^{736}\equiv4\cdot5^3+736\pmod{5^4}$, so $a=4$. Thus, we need to solve
$$
\begin{align}
d&\equiv 4\cdot3^3\equiv3&\pmod{5}\\
d&\equiv 736/2^3\equiv0&\pmod{2}
\end{align}
$$
so $d=8$, and the next term in the sequence is $k=8736$ for $n=4$.

$2^{8736}\equiv4\cdot5^4+8736\pmod{5^5}$, so $a=4$. Thus, we need to solve
$$
\begin{align}
d&\equiv 4\cdot3^4\equiv4&\pmod{5}\\
d&\equiv 8736/2^4\equiv0&\pmod{2}
\end{align}
$$
so $d=4$, and the next term in the sequence is $k=48736$ for $n=5$.

$2^{48736}\equiv3\cdot5^5+48736\pmod{5^6}$, so $a=4$. Thus, we need to solve
$$
\begin{align}
d&\equiv 3\cdot3^5\equiv4&\pmod{5}\\
d&\equiv 48736/2^5\equiv1&\pmod{2}
\end{align}
$$
so $d=9$, and the next term in the sequence is $k=948736$ for $n=6$.

etc.